# Castle Windsor Captive dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

**Prerequisites:**

- Castle Windsor 4.1.0
- Net Framework 4.7.2
- A large sequence of parallel requests

**Parties:**

- API controller
- Service A as a singleton (default lifestyle for Castle Windsor)
- Service B as a scoped, injected to the Service A

**Error:**

1. Time to time the Service B, during method execution throws a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Questions:**

- Is it valid from my side to guess that, the Service B (scoped), at some time can be disposed, thus, it can be reasonable for the issue (null reference exception). Unfortunately, was able to reproduce it locally, thus, need to get some confirmation for my thoughts
- How the scoped service behave itself when there is an unhandled error occurred, will it be disposed ? Can it be reason of the issue ?
- I would be very grateful if there is advice on how to reproduce this locally

Comment: Without more details about the error, it's impossible to say anything useful regarding the error. A stack trace would likely be helpful, including more details. It's also not possible for anyone to comment on the behavior of the scoped/disposed service or any part of your system, as you didn't show any of the details.

Comment: Since this is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) it could be very hard to reproduce locally. My best bet is that another thread is accessing the scoped object (or one of its dependencies) while another thread is disposing the object (and with it setting fields to `null`). But the real question is: why are you injecting a `Scoped` instance into a `Singleton` instance, especially since you already seem to understand the concept of a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Wouldn't it be time to simply refactor this solution?

Comment: Actually, there is some kind of investigation of existed system in prod. And it also reason why, I can't provide more specific context or log trace. My intention just to try to found out the root cause of the issue. Thus, I just try to verify my thought. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I would say that you already know what the root cause is: Service B is a Captive dependency.